# Convert SDK's url to nsIURI

Tags: url, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a proper way to convert a [`nsIURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIURI) to an [Addon `url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/url)?

They share many properties, but differ in some (f.ex. the addon url has a`.hash` property where `nsIURL` has `ref`).

Is it recommended to simply use the property ([duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)) with a failover (f.ex. `url.hash || url.ref`) or is there a simple way to convert between these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proved to be hard to do, as the types are neither compatible not always complete.

As a workaround, use the `uri.spec` string internally, and only convert when needed for some methods.